# Jasper reports does not include JRScriptlet?

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
 public void makeReportAddToPanel()
   {


       JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();//a new report

       report
          .columns(
              Columns.column("Applicant", "ApplicantName", DataTypes.stringType()),
              Columns.column("Quiz", "Quiz", DataTypes.integerType()),
              Columns.column("Score", "Score", DataTypes.integerType()))
                .title(//title of the report
              Components.text("Score Per Quiz")
              .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER))
              .pageFooter(Components.pageXofY())//show page number on the page footer
              .setDataSource("Select answer,userId,questionId from quizTaken",dao.Connection.getDBConnection());

        try {
                    //show the report
            JRViewer view = new JRViewer(report.toJasperPrint());
            report.show();
            this.add(view);

                    //export the report to a pdf file
            report.toPdf(new FileOutputStream("/report.pdf"));
        } catch (DRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
```

This is the stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRScriptlet
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.base.JasperReportDesign.init(JasperReportDesign.java:82)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.base.JasperReportDesign.<init>(JasperReportDesign.java:76)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.base.JasperReportDesign.<init>(JasperReportDesign.java:69)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toJasperReportDesign(JasperReportBuilder.java:260)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.getJasperParameters(JasperReportBuilder.java:287)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toJasperPrint(JasperReportBuilder.java:298)
    at source.Report.makeReportaddToPanel(Report.java:134)
    at guiCompanyLevel.CompanyGui$MenuItemHandler.actionPerformed(CompanyGui.java:247)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So I am trying to build a report and putting it into a panel but when I run the code I get this error ... When I look into the jasperreport jar the package JRScriptlet is not included

Answer (score 0):

Your project is missing a dependency.

So, you must add the jasperreport-xxx.jar (with xxx corresponding to your targeted version) to your classpath.

If you're using maven add the GAV parameters to your pom.xml file with the adequate scope (compile by default).

Comment: the jar is included into the project https://gyazo.com/2b883755563aa98ffb5ccfa355aca0f2

i think i dont understand your answer well

i've never used jasper reports before so excuses for my stupidity :p